# Change the display of Safari with ReactNativeKeycloak in-app browser options

Tags: ios, react-native, keycloak

I am trying to change the display of the following login with keycloak page.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2j78.jpg
This shows up with Safari when starting the app.

The problem I have is that the user has to scroll to see the " New user " part of my WebView. And this is a problem.
I'd like to change the display of my WebView to make it look like this if possible :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ss01.jpg
Here I had to manually unzoom the page.

```
<ReactNativeKeycloakProvider
      authClient={keycloak}
      onEvent={onEvent}
      initOptions={{
        redirectUri: 'mobile://presentation',
        inAppBrowserOptions: {
          ephemeralWebSession: true,
          modalEnabled: true,
        },
      }}>
```

This is the code displaying the Keycloak Login page in Safari ( https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-native-keycloak ).
I've checked the different InAppBrowser options here : https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser#ios-options

When changing the values of each of these options, I can see no differences on the iPhone I'm using. When I change 'ephemeralWebSession' from true to false, I can see the difference. But every other option makes no difference for me. I tried to change 'modalTransitionStyle', 'modalPresentationStyle', 'readerMode' and 'preferredBarTintColor' values, but nothing shows different on the WebView.

I don't understand what I should change to get my WebView to change aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is about 6 months old as I'm writing this answer, but I had this same issue and came across this in a search.

There is an open issue with InAppBrowser that addresses this: https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/292

In short, RN Keycloak calls the InAppBrowser `openAuth` method to start an `ASWebAuthenticationSession` instead of a typical web session with the `open` method. `ASWebAuthenticationSession` is not customizable, per Apple.

So, the choice is to modify the RN Keycloak package to use the `open` method, or to do some overriding trickery with Objective-C as found here: https://msolarana.netlify.app/2021/01/06/fixing-aswebauthenticationsession-presentation/

Comment: And, as it turns out, simply switching to the `open` method doesn't work.